# get numbers from url using regex

Tags: regex

i want to page redirection and unable to write condition for it

have different scenario want to redirect friendly url to query string base

```
http://www.domainname.com/directoryname/friendly-url-goes-here_123456.html
```

friendly-url-goes-here can be like this friendly_url-goes_23-here_123456.html, i just want 123456

and page get redirected to this

```
http://www.domainname.com/detail-page?id=123456
```

123456 will be a variable

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: want to do it using .htaccess, using PHP ( wordpress )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
\d+(?=\D*$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

**.htaccess:**

Inside your root .htaccess you can use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^directoryname/.*?(\d+)\D*$ /detail-page?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC,R]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)

#### [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite but its not redirecting

Comment: It is a silent rewrite. If you want redirect then add `R` flag to make it `[L,QSA,NC,R]`. Also do you .htaccess in `directoryname` also?

Comment: .htaccess is on root domain.com

Comment: using basic wordpress rewrite rules from here http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anubhava, can you please guide me where form i can learn all these pattern stuff

Comment: I am adding references to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this could be one way to do it:

```
(\d+).html$
```

- **`\d+`** match a digit [0-9]

[**Online Demo 1**](http://regex101.com/r/pX4cO3/1)

and this is another way:

```
\d+(?=\.html$)
```

- **`(?=.html$)`** It is a positive lookahead - it assert that the regex below can be matched if it contains at end(`$`) a `.html`

[**Online Demo 2**](http://regex101.com/r/pX4cO3/3)